# Check height of several elements and add class if height > x

Tags: jquery, html, css, function

**What I have:** I have four spans with the class .cta-title being dynamically generated.

**What I need:** I need to check the height of these spans, and add a class to any where the height is greater than 34px.

**What I have tried:**

I have this sitting in my jquery file. Another function in it is working so no problems with linking it. Console.log($(this.height()) logs the heights correctly, so the problem must lie beyond that.

edit: http://jsfiddle.net/AHv7v/

edit 2: I have no idea what I did (the function is still the same) but it seems to be working now. I will keep looking to see if I can find out what made this change. Thanks and sorry!

```
$(function(){
  var $tArray = $('div.cta').children('.cta-title');
  $tArray.each(function(){
    if ($(this).height() > 34) {
        $(this).addClass('two-line');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You should make a jsfiddle.net so we can see what you have and play with it. You're likely to get a faster answer.

Comment: What does `console.log($(this).height())` inside of your `each()` tell you about the heights?

Comment: the console is showing the heights correctly in numbers.

Comment: so the `(this).height` is greater than 34 but it doesn't execute the expression inside the if?

Comment: Correct. It logs 34, 68, 34, 34.

Comment: The JS Fiddle didn't work because you *didn't include jQuery*, corrected: http://jsfiddle.net/AHv7v/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) to get the heights of your elements. It is similar to directly accessing the `offsetHeight` property of DOM 2/3 elements.

This should cover for everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what I did (the function is still the same) but it seems to be working now, which is odd because the jsfiddle still doesn't work. I will keep looking to see if I can find out what made this change.